# Random pertubation about a constant

Tags: matlab

How can I generate a vector on which every element be a  pertubation about a constant in MATLAB?

For example if the constant be 1, the vector be [1.01 0.94 0.97 1.03 ,......].

The rand function returns a matrix. But how could I determine  it about a constant.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of random distribution? Uniform distribution between a and b? Normal distribution?

Comment: what's wrong with `result = myConst + rand( 1, n );` ?

Comment: The kind of distribution  is not important for me,

Comment: I need to small pertubation, for example at most 10e-1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a small noise around a constant signal then:

```
>> res = myConst + myMag * ( -1 + 2 * rand( 1, n ) );
```

Will give you a vector with `n` entries with uniformly distributed noise between `[-myMag MyMag]` around `myConst`.

For example:

```
n=5;
myMag=1e-1;
n=5;
myConst=1;
res = myConst + myMag * ( -1 + 2 * rand( 1, n ) )

res =
1.0986    0.9511    0.9903    1.0920    1.0939
```